# Switch between AWS and localstack on network level

Tags: java, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, localstack

Can somebody tell me please if there is some minimal-impact solution to switch between AWS- and localstack env? Might it be serverless-localstack?

I have a series of node.js- java-ee- and spring-boot services, which are deployed as docker-containers (AWS ecs) and inter-connected via AWS sqs and other AWS services.

I imagined using localstack was like the picture here from localstack.cloud and I would switch a real AWS env with a localstack env without the need to change the application code and - even better: the docker-container. The below schema encouraged me that it might really be as simple as that:
[image]

I would just change some options in a docker-compose-file or like manipulating a /etc/hosts file where I replace a set of "real" AWS-URLs by localhost:3456. And that's it.

Isn't there something like this? Do I really have to change every single microservice?

As I start to dive deeper I get more and more confused:

- Most tutorials never describe application level but show some calls with "aws --endpoint-url ..." That's nice, but I guess, my node- or java-service won't call the aws shell command, right?
- On application level this would mean that I have to change code for different environments, replace beans by profile in java and import different ones, wouldn't it? 
  For java this would mean:
  .withEndpointConfiguration(new EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:4575", "eu-west-1")
  For the node.js-module sqs-consumer I saw similar solutions...

  These URL changes could have been done on a more abstract level, couldn't they?
- https://github.com/temyers/serverless-localstack sounds like the above imagined solution but there seems not to be much change and there is a heavy WIP-warning. Any experience with this?

So again - can somebody tell me if there is some easy minimal-impact solution to switch between AWS- and localstack env like some sort of "redirect"?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 1/2 years later I think I know the answer. It's "kubernetes and minikube" instead of "AWS and localstack".

With some minor exceptions there is the rule: "A node is a node is a node", whether you deploy it on your local minikube or on some remote cloud-cluster.

During development I execute e2e-tests on my local minikube, whereas Jenkins does the same e2e-tests on some ad-hoc test-cluster and you even could run the same tests remotely on the production-cluster - all done by the same "Kubernetes client".